# JQuery Change Background Image Reverts Back to Old One

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, json, mongodb

I have a web application which allows the user to create and view interactive stories...

One functionality is to change the background image - the file path of the uploaded image is saved within a javascript object and posted as JSON to a MongoDB database.

When I use this app to change the uploaded image with a new one and save it - it works fine.

However when I retrieve the JSON from the database and apply the url stored there later it uses the old one rather than the updated one...

This code saves the story...

```
function saveStory(){

var numpages=$('.page').length;

var book=new Object();

$.getJSON('../scripts/getUser.php').done(function(data){
    book.title=title;
    book.user=data._id.$id;
    book.pages=new Array();

    var page;
    var link;

    for (var i=0;i<numpages;i++){
        var numlinks=$('#p'+i+' .link').length;
        page=new Object();
        page.text=$('#p'+i+' .textarea').text();
        page.image=$('#p'+i).css('background-image').replace(/^url\(["']?/, '').replace(/["']?\)$/, '');

        page.links=new Array();

        for (var j=0;j<numlinks;j++){
            link=new Object();
            link.text=$('#p'+i+'l'+j+' .linktext').text();
            link.locale=$('#p'+i+'l'+j+' .locale').text();

            page.links.push(link);
        }
        book.pages.push(page);
    }
}).then(function(){ $.post('../scripts/addstory.php', {book: book})});
 }
```

This code opens it...

```
function openStory(){
var story=$('#thestory').text();
$.post('../scripts/getstory.php', {story: story}, function(book){

var numpages=book.pages.length;

    for (var i=0;i<numpages;i++){

        var numlinks=book.pages[i].links.length;

        $('#content').append("<div id=p"+ i +" class='page'><div class='textarea' contentEditable='true'>" + book.pages[i].text + "</div></div>");

        $('#p'+i).css('background-image', 'url(' + book.pages[i].image.replace(/^url\(["']?/, '').replace(/["']?\)$/, '') + ')');

        for (var j=0;j<numlinks;j++){
            $('#p' + i).append("<div id=p"+ i +"l"+ j +" class='link'><div class='linktext' contentEditable='true'>"+ book.pages[i].links[j].text +"</div><div class='locale' contentEditable='true'>"+ book.pages[i].links[j].locale +"</div></div>");
        }
    }
}, 'json');
 }
```

I checked whether it was saving the correct url into the json and it was.

I saved the story and then I refresh the page - it calls openStory() where the url of the image changes back to the old one!

The puzzling thing is that the url value in the database has been updated but somehow it digs up the old value.

Does anyone know how to fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There doesn't seem to be enough information here to solve this. I suspect the problem could be in the html (or maybe php).

What is the value in #thestory?

In the response from getstory, what is the value of image? Is it correct coming from the server. This would indicate that your problem is in the php rather than JavaScript.

Comment: #thestory contains the id which is used when querying the database for the correct story when opening.